# How to fix "permission denied" when typing "code ." in wsl?

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

typing "code ." in the WSL terminal, windows-ubuntu subsystem returns:
/c/Users/cj/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl-0.64.2/scripts/wslCode.sh: 63: /home/cj/.vscode-server/bin/f80445acd5a3dadef24aa209168452a3d97cc326/bin/remote-cli/code: Permission denied

the command "which code" returns:
/c/Users/cj/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin/code

I've tried completely reinstalling VSCode and Ubuntu, no luck. Any tips?